# Some fontawesomes are not working in html

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, font-awesome

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to access `font awesomes` `fas fa` sign BUT some signs are not showing. like **class="fas fa-crown"**

When i try to access `fas fa-crown` then it shows

```html
<i class="fas fa-crown" style="font-size: 24px; color: #EED974">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Which link i am using :-**

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**What have i tried :-**

I tried many links but nothing worked for me.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this link:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/crown?style=solid

the crown is on version 5.0.13 and you are using 5.0.8 - so it might be the issue

EDIT:

```html
<i class="fas fa-crown" style="font-size: 24px; color: #EED974">

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I've edit the post and removed the integrity part - basically if it is important to you, you can calculate the hash and add it again

Comment: Added the integrity check